# My dog is bleeding day and night

Tags: dogs, health, safety

My dog has been bleeding day and night, and was wondering what could be causing this? She seems to be bleeding from her private part of her body. My dog is and red nose pit bull (female). She is very happy and loving dog and didn very energetic too. She's a 2 year old dog which is 14 in dog years. I'm just not sure what to do. The bleeds aren't that bad but just enough to raise aren good bit of concern.

Comment: Take her to the vet. This could be from a number of things, and it needs to be checked out by a professional ASAP.

Comment: Is the bleeding coming from the vaginal or rectal area?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First - if your dog is bleeding when she shouldn't, or if you are in doubt - take her to the vet. If, for whatever reason, you can't take her to the vet, phone your vet. NOW.

Your dog is a young female. It is possible that she is in heat; first part of the [female reproductive cycle in dogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canine_reproduction#The_reproductive_cycle).
If this is the case **and you should verify with your vet that it is only that!!!** then you will want to keep her inside, unless you intend to have a litter of puppies. It may sound great to have puppies but unless you can provide them with a good home, which is hard, you shouldn't.

As for the "dog years is 7 times human years", this isn't really correct. It's an oversimplification, dog ages don't really map to human ages linearly.

Answer (score 8):

When in doubt, always call a vet.

Your female my be in estrus. In larger dogs, the first estrus occurs at 18 - 24 months of age (earlier for small dogs).

> In many cases, a bloody vaginal discharge will be the first thing that a pet owner will observe when their dog comes into heat. In some cases, the discharge will not be apparent until several days after estrus has begun. The amount of discharge varies with the individual dog; some dogs have only a tiny amount of discharge while others have heavy bleeding.

When my dogs come into heat, one of them consistently cleans up after herself, so I never see any blood. The second one isn't nearly as conscientious; I will know because I see drops of bright red blood scattered where she's been - not a lot - but definitely noticeable. After a few days, the blood becomes watery and much less noticeable.

Dogs can become pregnant on their very first estrus cycle; you need to keep her away from other dogs for *at least* two weeks.

A vet can easily tell if this is the cause of her bleeding by doing a vaginal swab and looking at the cells under a microscope. It doesn't cost much, and is always the right thing to do when you aren't sure what's going on, if the bleeding is heavier than in previous cycles (it sounds like this might be your dog's first cycle), or if she's bleeding out of cycle.

<sub>[Estrus Cycles in Dogs](http://www.vcahospitals.com/main/pet-health-information/article/animal-health/estrus-cycles-in-dogs/5778)</sub>
<sub>[How to Tell If Your Dog’s In Heat](http://pets.webmd.com/dogs/how-tell-if-dogs-heat)</sub>
<sub>[Canine Estrous Cycle](http://www.eastcentralvet.com/canine-estrous-cycle.pml)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Your female dog is probably in heat! Unless you want a litter of puppies you might want to keep your female puppy inside. Yeah I know puppies might sound all nice and cute but trust me there are a lot to take care of. So if you don't have a big house there's some space to provide them especially if they're pit bulls and if you don't have a lot of food or water especially water then you might want to keep your dog inside like I said so yeah I just thought this would be helpful. As us humans know it by a period.